# Java Regex to Validate Full Name allow only Spaces ,Letters,commas, dots in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to validate the given string. It should allow (a-z, white space between words,commas,dots only).

I tried this but it doesn't work:
 final String name = "/^[a-z]+(\s+[a-z]+)*$/i";

```
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(name );
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Ravi is a java developer");
      System.out.println("***********"+matcher.matches());
```

please suggest to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `white space between words,commas,dots only` could you provide an example which replicates this?

Comment: Your example `"Ravi is a java developer"` does not contain punctuation. Please include an example with commas and dots. (Are they also to be expected only between words? Can they form words of their own, i.e. be surrounded by whitespace? Can they the the first or last character?)

Comment: what do you think `/i` is doing in your regex?  This is Java, not `sed` or `perl`.  If you want to ignore case, prefix the regex with `(?i)` <--This is the standard way to trigger flags within a regex string in Java.  And get ird of the "/i" at the end, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The regex and example you provided will not work, as you don't allow capital letters.
You can try this:

```
([a-zA-Z]*(\s)*[\.\,]*)*
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable case insensitive modifier `(?i)`

```
String s = "Ravi is a java developer";
System.out.println(s.matches("(?i)[a-z]+(\\s+[a-z]+)*")); // true
```

OR

```
System.out.println(s.matches("(?i)[a-z]+([,.\\s]+[a-z]+)*")); // true
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the answer but it is not allowing dot.

Comment: @Ravi seems unclear for me. Could you provide an example  which satisfies your needs?

Answer (score 0):

This Should work:

```
String name = "[a-zA-z]*([,.\\s]+[a-z]*)*"
```

And this should be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Why complicate?

```
"^A-Z[a-z \\.,]+$" <-- something that starts with a capital letter and has only letters, space, dots and commas after that.
```

I'm surprised how complicated regexes the average person creates.